# How to remove html head body tags in layout magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, ajax, product-view, page-layouts

Controller

```
<?php

namespace Test\QuickView\Controller\Catalog\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\View
{
}
```

Layout

quickview_catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.container" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <container name="product.info.main" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-main" before="-">
                <container name="product.info.price" label="Product info auxiliary container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-price" after="product.info.review">
                    <container name="product.info.stock.sku" label="Product auxiliary info" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-info-stock-sku">
                        <container name="product.info.type" before="-"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" after="product.info.type">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                                <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
                                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.review" template="product/view/review.phtml" after="product.info.stock.sku" />
                    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final" after="product.info.sku">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                            <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
                            <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.tier" after="product.info.price">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
                        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">tier_price</argument>
                        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <container name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" label="Alert Urls" after="product.price.tier"/>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info" template="product/view/form.phtml" after="alert.urls">
                    <container name="product.info.form.content" as="product_info_form_content">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="product.info.form.options" as="options_container">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="product/view/options/wrapper.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="product/view/options.phtml">
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\DefaultType" as="default" template="product/view/options/type/default.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Text" as="text" template="product/view/options/type/text.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\File" as="file" template="product/view/options/type/file.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select" as="select" template="product/view/options/type/select.phtml"/>
                                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Date" as="date" template="product/view/options/type/date.phtml"/>
                            </block>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="Magento_Theme::js/calendar.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml">
                            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional" as="product.info.addtocart" template="product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>
                        </block>
                    </block>
                </block>
                <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
                    <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product-social-links" after="product.info.overview">
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.mailto" template="product/view/mailto.phtml"/>
                    </container>
                </container>
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="product.info.extrahint">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">overview</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Overview</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="description"</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
            <container name="product.info.media" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="product media" after="product.info.main">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery" name="product.info.media.image" template="product/view/gallery.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="copyright" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

when I go to
http://localhost/magento2/quickview/catalog_product/view/id/5
and view source, the page load full content with html head body tags.

I want use ajax get only content of product without html head body tags.

How to make this?

Answer (score 3):

I found a better way to get content for ajax calls using any layout and getting exactly the html markup block you need. 
I wanted to load products depending on the category chosen without a page load but with an ajax call. I created a controller, a block and its corresponding phtml. I tried creating also a layout .xml file for the controller but even in my best attempts I got the `<head>` with some undesired `css` or `js` files as a part of the response to the ajax call...

So I modified my controller in this way:

```
class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

protected $_registry;
protected $template;
protected $pageFactory;
protected $_translateInline;
protected $_resultRawFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template $template,
    \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RawFactory $resultRawFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Translate\InlineInterface $translateInline
)
{
    $this->_registry = $registry;
    $this->template = $template;
    $this->_resultRawFactory = $resultRawFactory;
    $this->_translateInline = $translateInline;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->_registry->register('categoryId', $this->getRequest()->getParam('categoryId'));
    $this->_registry->register('mode', $this->getRequest()->getParam('mode'));

    $html = $this->template->getLayout()->createBlock('Company\Catalog\Block\Product\AjaxCategoryContent')->toHtml();
    $this->_translateInline->processResponseBody($html);

    $resultRaw = $this->_resultRawFactory->create();
    $resultRaw->setContents($html);
    return $resultRaw;
}
}
```

So this controller is taking the two parameters provided and writing them in the registry, I use them later in the block.
It's creating the block directly there, keeping the html resultant and processing because it has translations/phrases.

And the most important part, instead of create and return the object  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page, it's creating a raw result \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Raw and setting its content with the html from the block.
The result is a piece of pure html markup without any `<head>` or `<body>`, or well uniquely the content of the phtml file.

Comment: What does your block file look like?

Answer (score 2):

To remove HTML head tags, Try this code:

```
<referenceContainer name="head" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="header" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="menu" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="notifications" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true"/>
<referenceContainer name="body" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: Try to make custom HTML which you want to show as result with use of Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

A solution more simple: create a new root.phtml only for you controller action.

In our controller:

```
class Index extends Action
{

/**
 * @var Onepage
 */
private $onepage;
private $resultPageFactory;

public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Onepage $onepage,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
)
{
    $this->onepage = $onepage;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    return parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    return $this->resultPageFactory->create(false, [
        'template' => 'GLB_Checkout::root.phtml',
    ]);
}
}
```

So, you create a new root.phtml in your-module/view/frontend/templates/root.phtml

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>It's working...</h1>
</body>
```

Sorry for indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 lines code in main controller file to call ajax template:

$resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
echo $resultPage->getLayout()->createBlock("VendorName\Module\Block\Product\Attr")->setTemplate("VendorName_Module::product/attr.phtml")->toHtml();