# Magento 2 layout with no html head or body tags for ajax output

Tags: magento2, layout, ajax, page-layouts

I'm attempting to output the wishlist block as an ajax request. I've attempted to do it in the controller using

```
$block = $resultPage->getLayout()
->createBlock('Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist','miniwishlist')            
->setTemplate('Company_Module::miniwishlist.phtml')
->toHtml();
```

But as the block contains several child blocks and I didn't have any success in using the setChild method programmatically.

I've since created a layout file that returns the block by itself. The problem is that output contains html, head, body tags, css and javascript.

I want to return **only** the block and nothing else. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I suspect you will need to create a new page layout, or use empty and remove `after.body.start` and `page.wrapper`.

Comment: I don't think it's that I used the template hints and only have two other blocks - require js and container which are above the wishlist block. In the html source code the block I want sits between the body tag. I want to get rid of everything else - html, body, head tags and all the css/javascript inside.  I could parse the output through domdocument - but that seems hacky.

Comment: Hmm `<html>` and `<body>` are added via `root.phtml`. Setting that page to use a new empty template (only including the code you require) instead of `root.phtml` may work? You can see this template being set in `vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/etc/di.xml` line 563 (for me at least). The root template can be seen in `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/base/templates/root.phtml`. I don't have the time to actually try it and provide a full answer sorry, if no one answer by the time I do I will give it a try and reply with a full answer.

Comment: In the block customer/Wishlist.php in the function _toHtml() if I replace "return parent::_toHtml()" with "die(parent::_toHtml());" I get the content I need using an unmodified layout in wishlist_index_index.xml. I may investigate going down that route.

Comment: You can read my answer here:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/121731/how-to-remove-html-head-body-tags-in-layout-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

I went about it differently, but got the result I was after, with very little modification.

I access the contents of the wishlist block using a modified url http://domain.com/wishlist/index/index/ajax/1

I've appended the 'ajax/1' to the normal wishlist request

In my module I overwrote the block \Magento\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist and modified the function _toHtml as follows:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if ($this->currentCustomer->getCustomerId()) {
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('ajax')) {
            die(parent::_toHtml());
        }
        else return parent::_toHtml();
    } else {
        return '';
    }
}
```

I also had to add the template file View.phtml to my module, which works nicely as I am able to modify that to get the desired output for my ajax call.