# Payment content showing with HTML tags on admin invoice pages

Tags: magento2, orders, invoice, payment, sales-invoice

1. Magento 1 version : 1.9.4.0
2. Magento 2 version : 2.3.5
3. Fresh install of m2
4. Run migrate:settings
5. Run migrate:data
   **All data is migrated**

We migrated data successfully but getting issues of html tags on invoice pages.
Admin->Sales->Invoices->Click on any invoice->Invoice page will open "Payment Information" under "Payment & Shipping Method" head here Data(content or description) showing in html tags.

**Expected result**

Data must be show WITHOUT HTML tags

**Actual result**

But here data is showing WITH HTML tags

Please check screenshot - 
[image]

I just changed vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/view/form.phtml

before - `<?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment') ?>`

now i using escaper function like this -

```
$data = $block->getChildHtml('order_payment');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
echo $escaper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($data);
```

Sample data(which i get on $data) -

```
<p>Western Union</p> <table> <tbody> <tr> <td><p><strong>WU Instructions: </strong>Western Union is a common way for people to send any currency to the USA. For Western Union you can either use their website, or go to a nearby Western Union store. Once you do this, email us back the information.</p><p>To find your nearest location, go to:<br><a href="http://locations.westernunion.com/" target="_blank">locations.westernunion.com</a><p>Bring your invoice, and this information with you to the Western Union store. This is the "Receiver" information: </p><p>* Name: <strong>john cloe </strong><br>* Street: <strong>123 b 108th mw</strong><br>* City, State & Zip: <strong>Seattle, Washington State, 98121</strong><br>* Country: <strong>USA </strong><br>* Phone: <strong>123-456-7890 </strong></p><p>When the money is sent, email us back: WU Control number; Senders full name, Senders City, State, and Country. That is it.</p></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

but still not working

Section -

```
<div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method<?php if ($_order->getIsVirtual()) : ?> order-payment-method-virtual<?php endif; ?> admin__fieldset-wrapper">
            <?php /*Billing Address */ ?>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-title">
                <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Payment Information')) ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="admin__page-section-item-content">
                <div class="order-payment-method-title">
                    <?php 
                    $data = $block->getChildHtml('order_payment');
                    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $allowableTags="<a>";
                    $result = strip_tags($data, $allowableTags);
                    echo $escaper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($result, $allowableTags);
                    ?>

                </div>
                <div class="order-payment-currency">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('The order was placed using %1.', $_order->getOrderCurrencyCode())) ?>
                </div>
                <div class="order-payment-additional"><?= $block->getChildHtml('order_payment_additional') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to remove this HTML tags ?

Comment: try below code mentioned in my answer

Comment: you are create custom payment information section ???

Comment: @MohitPatel No this is fresh magento installation and i just migrate data from M1 to M2

Comment: So fresh magento install and `form.phtml`  file copy and paste your migrate magento folder.i think you are understand

Comment: @MohitPatel yes i copied.But still not working,i just want to remove HTML tags

Comment: can you post this div <div class="admin__page-section-item order-payment-method"> you  questions ???

Comment: @MohitPatel please check i updated my question

Comment: i am not sure but try easy you go to xml file and remove https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/121770/85907

Comment: i dont think that it will work,it is other thing

Comment: i am not sure but try this solution `$data = $block->getChildHtml('order_payment');
$new_data = strip_tags($data, '<a>');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
echo $escaper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($new_data);` And after save remove var/view_process and run the `php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: @MohitPatel i already try this but not working

Comment: after save remove var/view_process and run the php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f ???

Comment: yes i removed view_processed and run both commands,now getting this - please check screenshot - https://prnt.sc/svulu3

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this ?

```
$data = $block->getChildHtml('order_payment');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$allowableTags="<a>";
$result = strip_tags($data, $allowableTags);
echo $escaper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Escaper')->escapeHtml($result, $allowableTags);
```

Comment: yes may be HTML tags directly coming from Payment gateway but it is working fine in M1 and i also edit my question,can you please check again my editable questions ?

Comment: can u give me sample html data which you receives in $data variable ?

Comment: i edited question put sample data

Comment: Please chek above code @sumeetbajaj

Comment: table tags gone but other tags is showing please check screenshot - https://prnt.sc/svulu3
you can compare screenshot in my question

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/34JxWqA.png - see it works for me.I used same $data in my local

Comment: maybe it is working in PHP but not in magento

Comment: no I tried in magento root itself.

Comment: can you please try direct here for testing purpose - vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/view/form.phtml